# Surface material on Saturn's moon Rhea

Tags: planetary-science

The Cassini mission has made several flybys of Saturn's second largest moon, Rhea.  Do we have any data about that moon's surface geochemistry?  I do know there is a thin Oxygen/Carbon Dioxide atmosphere and that the planet is 75/25 ice/rock.

Comment: Plenty: [VIMS coverage of Saturn’s icy satellite Rhea](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2009/pdf/1377.pdf), [Formation, Distribution and Loss of Rhea’s O2-CO2 Exosphere](http://www.virginia.edu/ep/LASP/RAB%20papers/Cassini/Teolis%20Rhea%20O2-CO3%20exosphere%2042%20LPSC%20(11)%202663.pdf), [Near-infrared spectroscopy of Mimas, Enceladus,
Tethys, and Rhea](http://web.eps.utk.edu/faculty/burr/pubs/05emery_etal_aa_satsats.pdf), [A spectroscopic study of the surfaces of Saturn’s large satellites:
H2O ice, tholins, and minor constituents](http://astrochemistry.org/docs/Cruikshanketal2005.pdf)...

Comment: ...[Differentiation and mineralogy of Rhea](http://meetingorganizer.copernicus.org/EPSC2013/EPSC2013-833-1.pdf), [Saturn’s Icy Moon Rhea: a Prediction for its 
Bulk Chemical Composition and Physical Structure](http://cds.cern.ch/record/913040/files/0512115.pdf), [Cassini RADAR observations of Enceladus, Tethys, Dione, Rhea, Iapetus, Hyperion, and Phoebe](http://trs-new.jpl.nasa.gov/dspace/bitstream/2014/40235/1/05-3668.pdf), and I would also suggest searching for Planetary and Space Science's "Surfaces, atmospheres and magnetospheres of the outer planets and their  satellites and ring systems"

Comment: The latter series of papers are sadly paywalled, all other links are to PDF documents. Are you interested in anything specific regarding Rhea's surface geochemistry, or just a general overview?

Comment: @TidalWave: Thanks for your responses.  I was wondering if there was a consensus yet about the presence of Ammonia in the ice.  I assumed the surface material is carbon-bearing silicates, but the reports seem to indicate higher abundances of metals than I originally thought.  A nice surprise, if it turns out to be true. . .  My reason for interest is to evaluate Rhea as a possible staging base for exploring the Saturn system.